# converting to Fluent NHibernate sessionmanager

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am changing my application to use Fluent NHibernate.  I have created my Fluent mapping files and have now moved onto configuring my Session Manager.  Currently, I use the following code -

```
private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
{
     return (new Configuration()).Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Along with my hibernate.cfg.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.InformixDialect1000</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OleDbDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myid;Data Source=mysource</property>

    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Does anyone know how I could transfer this to Fluent?  The problem I have having is with the Database portion of the configuration.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [informix support](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/source/browse/trunk/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/Db/IfxOdbcConfiguration.cs?spec=svn643&r=643) you will need to download the [latest fluent nhibernate binary](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) (#680 worked for me):

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(
            IfxOdbcConfiguration
                .Informix1000
                .ConnectionString("Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myid;Data Source=mysource")
                .Driver<OleDbDriver>()
                .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
                .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
        )
        .Mappings(
            m => m
                .FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<SomePersistentType>()
        )
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: Where does the ProxyFactoryFactory type come from in the above example?

Comment: From the `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle` assembly.

Comment: I had to add in .Driver<OleDbDriver>, but other than that it seems to be working.  Thanks

Comment: @czuroski, good point, I've edited my post to take it into account. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jon - Here is what I ended up using -

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    IfxOdbcConfiguration
                        .Informix1000
                        .ConnectionString("Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Data Source=database@server")
                        .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
                        .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
                        .Driver<OleDbDriver>()
                        .ShowSql()
                    )
                .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(persistenceModel))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, so let me know if that works.
thanks