# Confusion about selecting the suitable ORM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I use ASP.NET with a informix database.

I use a set of written classes to handle the connections, the CRUD operations, transactions, etc....

Now, I feel these classes are not the best choice, less performance,take a lot of time and have many drawbacks.

---

I want to use an ORM, but I don't know how to choose the one which suits my web applications (ASP.NET, Informix).

Please help to select the convenient ORM.

I'm confused among nHibernate, Entity Framework, LINQ To SQL, and the Open Access (Telerik Component).

Note: I will use Visual Studio 2012 so I want the recent comparison.

Comment: .NET ORMs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you thought about using Fluent NHibernate?  There's a wealth of articles on the web for it, and plenty on SO!!  Here's one such article : [converting to Fluent NHibernate sessionmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875127/converting-to-fluent-nhibernate-sessionmanager).

EDIT :

Been thinking about your situation and I'll tell you how I usually think.  Firstly, I'll think about exactly what it is I want my Gateway layer to do (this is the layer I use to talk to the persistance medium).  Now, most will say, I want it to talk to the database or I want to insert and update stuff.  But recently, I have found this isn't enough!  Halfway through coding a gateway layer with these questions in mind, I suddenly realised that I wanted to do something ever so slightly different, and boom, I couldn't do it using NHibernate very easily. So, I made a few concessions and went with Linq-ToSql as it supported what was a higher priority requirement over some of the niceties of NHibernate.

Now, the reason for my tale is this : NHibernate provides some great little features like Result Transformation.  I can have a view on my Db with masses of joined tables, giving an aliase for each field and with a lovely result transformer, bang, it's instantly transformed into my DTO. Now, don't get me wrong, Linq-To-Sql has a similar thing with the auto-generated classes.  But I don't want these visible outside of the gateway layer (another conversation). Equally, Linq-To-Sql handles transactions with ease - something I thought NHibernate didn't do so well!

So, it all boils down to : what are my EXACT requirements within my gateway/repository layer and what technologies are compatible with my persistance medium?!  And now, I can think about what technology I want to use.

I realise I may not have answered your question per se, but I hope it has given you something to think about!

Happy coding,
Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: To bad that Nhibernate query syntax is so complicated (is it only me?) that after working over a year on project that was using it I still had problems with it. Documentation for Hibernate and Fluent is almost non helpful at all. Lucky that we have now google and sites like SO. There are few query syntaxes. So in big project you can always find something funny (with big team it's not really helpfull). With such convoluted queries it is not hard to write n+1 query, which pass test on small data list but will fail miserably on production. No easy way to check sql string from code, better to use

Comment: SQL profiller which itself is not such user friendly tool. Fluent NH has also drawbacks. For starters I has long start time since it is compiled to hbml anyway. So in big DB this could be a problem. Etc etc. For me bigest drawback is no support for LINQ (or montly not working). Why omit native query language syntax and add NH specific? You have to learn yet another one. I admit that NH is highly configurable and feature rich but I still look ahead for another and better. Maybe LightSwitch?

Answer (score 10):

I'd really suggest Entity Framework, as it is the native framework of .NET. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565) it is stated that an Informix provider is available for EF.

Comment: EF is great (easy to use, has a lot of db providers, out of the box or on free projects here and there, has a perfectly working LINQ provider) but also lacks obvious things, like events, logging, caching or bulk inserts/updates. Also, code-first is very new, I hadn't have the chance to test it with it.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0903linqentity/

The link above will provide you with links to download the informix provider, as well as take you through a step by step process of using the informix provider in conjunction with Entity Framework.

More about Entity Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Simply put, once you have this set up you will be able to create classes that map to your informix data structures and perform queries using linq. EF is quite a powerful and useful tool, I recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

My vote is with Fluent NHibernate - you get the configurability and cross-platform usage of Hibernate but you get to obviate the necessity of using massive XML configuration files. Entity Framework is good, but I don't like tools which rely too much on IDE/Designer support.

Happy coding,

Mel

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Fluent NHibernate. Personally I see it used in more companies than any other ORM framework.

I've used Entity Framework, both design-first, which has serious lock-in drawbacks, and code-first, which is okay.

I posted [an answer on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5762) when someone was asking an almost identical question.

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to read this book first :
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-Design-Patterns.productCd-0470292784.html